# Vector graphics formats: SVG , EPS or PDF

Tags: pdf, graphics, latex, vector-graphics, svg

How does the vector graphics formats [svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) , [eps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) and [pdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) compare against each other(Quality, filesize etc)?

If I can generate(eg matplotlib) plot in any of the above formats, which format should I choose for output?

(Optional) Assume that the output graph is to be published using Tex.

I know that if the output is in pdf, its easy to be included in tex. But are there any quality differences between the formats? What are the other considerations that would make one of the formats preferable?

Comment: What kind of quality differences do you expect in vector graphics formats?

Comment: if they are the same quality, why are there different formats?

Comment: difference may not be quality, i havent observed any...may be there are other considerations

Comment: If you are using pdftex (or luatex) then go for the pdf output. You have to convert the files otherwise.